# How to send message to azure IOT hub in C++

Tags: c++, azure-iot-hub

I am working on `c++` project and I have a json data which I need to send to `azure` IoT hub. I tried searching for this but didnt get any good results. I checked and found good support for this in c# but not in c++. Is there any library to do that. Any good working examples. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a C IoT Hub SDK:

- There's a [quickstart here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-c).
- [C SDK GitHub repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c).
- [Additional device samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/tree/master/iothub_client/samples)